# Tkinter - binded lamba function to return value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, oop, tkinter

I am bulding rather simple Tkinter application but I would like to stick to OOP. Therefore whole application is splitted into different classes.

One of the class is Mathematical Calculations which is making different calculations based on Pandas's dataframe (DF). One of methods of this class is average which returns average.

I have binded this method to one of buttons to show this average (using Tkinter's messagebox):

```
class MathematicalCalculations():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def average(self, df, measurement, **kwargs):
        #sets relevant row for iloc
        rowToCheck = (df.loc[df.isin([measurement]).\
                        any(axis=1)].index)

        column1 = kwargs.get('column1')
        column2 = kwargs.get('column2')
        quater = kwargs.get('quater')
        
        
        if column1 is None:
            secondColumn = len(df.columns)
            firstColumn = secondColumn-int(quater)
        elif "/" in column1:
            firstColumn = (df.columns.get_loc(column1)) 
            secondColumn = (df.columns.get_loc(column2))

        average = str(df.iloc[rowToCheck, firstColumn:secondColumn+1].mean(axis=1,skipna=True, numeric_only=True))
        average = average.split()
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Average", message=average[1])
```

Here are details of binded button:

```
self.Bquatersaverage.bind("<Button-1>", \
                lambda bb: MathematicalCalculations().average( \
                df = DataDownloader().SQL_to_DF(self.getmarkerfromLBmarkers(parent, listofcompanies), self.getmeasurementfromLBmeasurement(parent, listofmeasurements)), \
                measurement=  self.getmeasurementfromLBmeasurement(parent, listofmeasurements), \
                quater = self.getquatersfromEBquaters(parent, datequateranges)))
```

As you can see I am using lambda to avoid immediate execution of MathematicalCalculations().average (as first user must choose few parameters). Problem is that if I would like to return mean (not Tkinter's message box) I am unable to reference function's return (average).

Is that possible to have a callback from function which is binded to button using lambda function? If that is not possible my method to calculate average will not be re-usable which stands in opposite to OOP.

Access return value from class method using binding to button (lamba function).

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to get the return value from a function called via `bind`. That function is being called by `mainloop` which throws away all return values. Your only choice is for the function to set a global or instance variable that can be accessed by other places in your code.

The best solution is to have a standalone function that does the computation and returns the result, and a separate function that is called via the bind that then calls this other function.

It might look something like this, though I don't know for sure where  some of the parameters come from so I'm guessing they are attributes of the widget. You can pass them in, but it's often easier to save them as attributes to keep the function signatures small.

```
def compute_average(event):
    parent = event.widget.parent
    listofcompanies = event.widget.listofcompanies
    listofmeasurements = event.widget.listofmeasurements
    dataquateranges = event.widget.dataquaterranges 

    marker = self.getmarkerfromLBmarkers(parent, listofcompanies)
    measurement = self.getmeasurementfromLBmeasurement(parent, listofmeasurements)
    df = DataDownloader().SQL_to_DF(marker, measurement)
    quater = self.getquatersfromEBquaters(parent, datequateranges)

    self.average = MathematicalCalculations().average(df=df, measurement=measurement, quater=quater)
```

This makes your code much easier to understand, and much easier to debug since you're able to stop the function at any point to examine the intermediate steps. It also makes it possible to have a very  simple call to `bind`:

```
self.Bquatersaverage.bind("<Button-1>", compute_average)
```

In this example, `compute_average` sets an instance attribute to the result, but you could also update a label, save it to a file, or do whatever else you want to do.